# React - call api and export value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm learning react and I took template as an example, I would like change menu values. The menus are create with fixed values, and I need to access my API and get values from the database, but when I try do that, I get an error return:

```
const LoadNavigation = async () => {
    return await axios.get('https://localhost:44362/api/SystemMenus').then(response => response.data);
}

var nav = LoadNavigation();

export const navigations = nav;
```

Error:

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
> In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.

If I pass the fixed export value (json) it works:

```
export const navigations = [
    {
        name: 'Home',
        path: '/dashboard',
        icon: 'home',
    },
    {
        label: 'Dashboards',
        type: 'label',
    },
    {
        name: 'Test 1',
        icon: 'trending_up',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Test 02',
                iconText: 'CP',
                path: '/test/test02',
            },
            {
                name: 'Test 03',
                iconText: 'FC',
                path: '/test/test03',
            },
        ],
    },
    
]
```

Another point is that my API is called after my const has been exported.

[image: Promise]

How do I solve these two problems, I couldn't find anything similar or that I could understand.

I did a lot of testing and modifying the code, but I can't get it to work.

**EDIT - Answer @Giovanni Esposito**

In this case it occurs and calls API

import axios from 'axios';

navigationsAPI.js

```
export const LoadNavigation = async () => {
    let response = await axios.get('https://localhost:44362/api/SystemMenus');
    return response.data;
}
```

navigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoadNavigation } from 'app/navigationsAPI'

var nav = LoadNavigation();

export const navigations = nav;
```

Error:

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order
> to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator
> method.

[image: Error3]

**EDIT - Answer @Drew Reese**

In this case only the error occurs, it does not call API

navigationsAPI.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const LoadNavigation = () => {
    return axios.get('https://localhost:44362/api/SystemMenus')
        .then(response => response.data);
}
```

navigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoadNavigation } from 'app/navigationsAPI'

const [nav, setNav] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    LoadNavigation().then(setNav);
}, []);


export const navigations = nav;
```

Error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

[image: Erro2]

Comment: LoadNavigation is an async function so it will return promise try using var nav=LoadNavigation.then(response => (return response))

Comment: I tried removing async and await and the result was the same. I tried to follow your tip but there is a syntax error, the error is *(return response)*. Is this after the LoadNavigation method?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your system and browser supports [top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await) (*or similar behavior*) this isn't possible to make the code wait for the response & handling before the `navigations` is exported. This probably isn't what you want to do anyway.

To handle this normally you could export the `LoadNavigation` function, and use a local `navigations` state variable and mounting effect to fetch and load the menu data.

```
export const LoadNavigation = () => {
  return axios.get('https://localhost:44362/api/SystemMenus')
    .then(response => response.data);
}
```

In consuming component;

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [navigations, setNavigations] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    LoadNavigation().then(setNavigations); // *
  }, []);

  ...

}
```

**** Note:** Here `LoadNavigation().then(setNavigations);` is passing the `setNavigations` function as the `.then` callback, but if it's more clear you can use an anonymous callback and proxy the response data.*

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  LoadNavigation().then(data => setNavigations(data));
}, []);
```

Comment: Drew Reese, I followed your example, for me a little more complex, and I had another error other than the initial one, but this time the API is not called, anything else I can do? I edited the post to demonstrate the result. Thanks

Comment: @user8223022 You can't call React hooks outside a function component (*or custom hook*). Sorry, I assumed you understood how React hooks work. See [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). I'll update my answer to make this overtly clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could adopt also this way:

**navigationsAPI.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';   

export const LoadNavigation = async () => {  
  let response = await axios.get('https://localhost:44362/api/SystemMenus');
  return response.data;
}
```

In any component in which you need to load navigation:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { LoadNavigation } from './navigationsAPI'

const Component = () => {
   const [navigation, setNavigation] = useState();

   useEffect(() => {
      LoadNavigation().then(response => setNavigation(response));
      
   }, []);

   return (...);
}
```

Comment: Giovanni Esposito, I tried to follow your example but i had the same initial problem. I edited the post to demonstrate. If you have any other solution, thank you

Comment: @user8223022 I saw your editing and I think that maybe I was not clear.  Let me edit my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, I'm trying to understand all this, but when I follow your example, the same problem as the *Drew Reese* example occurs, as it is in the original post. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: @user8223022 most probably because you are calling `useEffect` outside a component. This s mandatory for React otherwise you got this error. If you don't know what is a component you could read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: actually the error occurs ```const [navigation, setNavigation] = useState();```. But is the cause also because it is outside a component?

Comment: @user8223022 Yes of course: `useEffect` and `useState` are hooks.